# useState updates state after second click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm a Java developer but recently interested with ReactJs. I'm still newbie. I'm working on a demo project using redux and react hooks. I'm having a hard time creating a collabsible nested component using react-collapsed package.

Here is my component:

```
import useCollapse from "react-collapsed";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {changeBrand} from "../../redux/actions/brandActions";
import initialState from "../../redux/reducers/initialState";

export const Collapsible = props => {

    const {brands} = props;
    const currentBrand = useSelector(state => state.changeBrandReducer);

    const [series, setSeries] = useState(initialState.currentSeri);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const {getCollapseProps, getToggleProps, isExpanded} = useCollapse();

    const selectBrand = brand => {
        dispatch(changeBrand(brand));
        showSeries();
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setSeries(currentBrand.series);
        console.log("Current brand : " + currentBrand.name);
    }, [currentBrand]);

    const showSeries = () => {
        return (
            console.log(series)
            // <div>
            //     {
            //         series.map(seri => (
            //             <div {...getCollapseProps()} key={seri.id}>
            //                 <div className="content" key={seri.id}>{seri.name}</div>
            //             </div>
            //         ))
            //     }
            // </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {brands.map(brand => (
                <div className="collapsible" key={brand.id}>
                    <div className="header" {...getToggleProps()} key={brand.id}
                         onClick={() => selectBrand(brand)}>
                        {brand.name}
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

In this struct there is a brand list and a series list inside of it. When I call the component, brandList renders but when I click an item of brandList, it says series is undefined. When I debug it, I realized after the first click, useState doesnt update series. It updates the variable after second click with previous selected item. How can I get changed value immediately?

Comment: I would try to define a new state var like :
const [selectedBrand, setSelectedBrand] = useState(null); which update each time you click on a brand.
Or maybe you should define a useEffect which setSeries each time your props.brand change (reducer var changed with your dispatch function)

Comment: I tried your first advice but nothing changed

Comment: And how about the 2nd suggestion ?